# VirtualBox inside Hyper V guest

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtualbox

I am trying to run a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox (configured using Vagrant) installed on a Win 8.1 guest running inside a Win 2012 R2 Hyper V host.
I disabled Hyper V on the Win 8.1 guest.  I am receiving "vt-x not available" when starting the VirtualBox guest.

Can I nest VirtualBox inside a Hyper V VM?

Comment: Can the query be moved to a more relevant site?  It wasn't an hypothetical question.  I did have this issue & ended up repurposing a physical machine.

Comment: Moderators, why is this question considered off-topic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Server 2012 R2 and older versions, Hyper-V does not expose VT extensions to the guests. This is why you can't run Hyper-V (or many other hypervisors) inside of Hyper-V there.

But Windows 10 (starting with update 1607), server 2016 and later versions, support nested virtualisation. This means that you can use virtualbox inside hyperV virtual machine with vagrant to configure the virtual box virtual machine.

What you need to do first is to enable virtualisation extensions on the target virtual machine from the host workstation (server 2016 etc.), via powershell:

```
Get-VM | where Name -eq "your_vm_name" | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Information: **Configuring a virtual machine on virtualbox with vagrant uses a lot of resources.** So be shure to give your "host virtual machine" at least 12 GB of ram and 4 virtual CPUs (hyperv > your vmachine > Settings > Processor > 4 virt processors. And ..> Memory > set to 16000 MB).

Comment: It is possible with current version of Hyper-V. Changing a setting via `powershell`: `Get-VM | where state -eq ‘Off’ | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true` works for me.

https://wibier.me/expose-virtualization-extensions-to-hyper-v-virtual-machine/